# How to update an item in a List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List<>

I need to modify single row item of the list.

```
List.Where(x => x.Amount>0).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList()
.ForEach(x => x.Amount = x.Amount + (item1- item2));
```

Above code is work for multiple rows but I want to select the first row of the list using conditions and update or modified only first-row item value.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating properties in Lists of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908980/updating-properties-in-lists-of-lists)

Comment: try "First" instead of "Where"

Comment: @Lucifer  No, my question is different

Comment: Your condition is bit weird how are you deciding which Id's amount should be updated by selecting first you will just update value of the first element which ever in the list it is

Comment: No your question seems same to me you want to update property of one element in your list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to objects - select first object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503/linq-to-objects-select-first-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
List.Where(x => x.Amount>0).OrderBy(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()?.Amount += (item1- item2);
```

Comment: Bear in mind you may get a null ref exception if there is no item in the list with Amount > 0...

Comment: @PawanLakhara can you try it now?

Comment: Thanks It Works i am using List.Where(x => x.Amount>0).OrderBy(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().Amount += (item1- item2);

Comment: This code should not compile because if the result is `null` you may end up with this => `null += (item1- item2);`. The compiler will yell at you for this kind of thing.

Comment: In my case List have at least one record with Amount.

Answer (score 4):

So you can just use `FirstOrDefault` extension method like below:

```
var item = List.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Amount > 0);
if (item != null) 
{
    item.Amount += item1- item2;
}
```

**Side Note:** the condition is a bit weird. The first row returned can be different on each time you execute the query.

Comment: best answer, though original question contains an `OrderBy()` - if the OP wants to edit the earliest/latest order only this would need to be added (well, would be better to know the ID you want and include that in the filter really)

Comment: @PawanLakhara What do you mean by _not useful this create no object_? More precisions make us forward in a better solution.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I Mean this create new object not useful for me.

Comment: Nope. You’re wrong. It references the same object in the list. Just check it yourself with ==